# You have 3 black balls and 4 white ones. You take 3 balls 6 times. What is the probability that you get the 3 black balls in a row only twice?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> There are seven balls in a box, 3 white and 4 black.
>
> Consider the experiment that consists on taking 3 balls without
>   replacing and checking their colors.
>
> You do this experiment 6 times with the same conditions.
>
> What is the probability of getting , in the six extractions, 3 black
>   balls in a row only twice?

First I tried to calculate the probability of getting 3 black balls in a row in one extraction:

$$\frac{3}{7}\cdot \frac{2}{6}\cdot \frac{1}{5} = \frac{1}{35}$$

Then I made A = got the 3 black balls = $\frac{1}{35}$, B = opposite of A = $\frac{34}{35}$. What I need is all the combinations of:

$$AABBBB = \frac{1}{35}\cdot\frac{1}{35}\cdot\frac{34}{35}\cdot\frac{34}{35}\cdot\frac{34}{35}\cdot\frac{34}{35} = \frac{272}{1225}$$

Which is $^6C_2=15$, so the answer would be $15 \cdot \frac{272}{1225}$ which is wrong.

My book states the solution is $0.0109$. What went wrong?

Comment: Your formula is correct. Just some manipulation mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one trial, the probability of getting $3$ black balls in a row is

$$\frac{3}{7}\times\frac{2}{6}\times\frac{1}{5}=\frac{1}{35}$$

In six trials, the probability of getting $3$ black balls in a row twice only is

$$\binom{6}{2}\left(\frac{1}{35}\right)^2\left(1-\frac{1}{35}\right)^4=\frac{4009008}{367653125}\approx 0.010904$$

Comment: Right, I added instead of multiplying. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

your result is wrong because your calculation is wrong.
AABBBB is not 272/1225. Calculate again